# LongListSelector style for Listview in Windows devices WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone, and I love how the LongListSelector control works. How there are letters/numbers which you click on to bring the specified letter into view.

But from what I have seen in my research, the LongListSelector is only available for Windows-Phone devices.

Are there any way to implement the alphabetical sorting and this:

[image]

... into the normal WPF Listview and use it for PC-devices?

Comment: Just try this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2009/07/16/wpf-xaml-listboxes-with-a-grouping-capability.aspx

Comment: @Sajeetharan Awesome! Did not see this functionality built in somewhere! Thank you